# Fix:I have add sinch jar file into libs folder and as library in android studio but when I import sinch or related class its not show import option

Tags: java, android-studio, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

public class SinchService extends Service {

```
private static final String APP_KEY = "7b6f87ff-75ea-4-aae5192e52";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "";
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "clientapi.sinch.com";

public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
private SinchClient mSinchClient;
private String mUserId;
```

Comment: Please answer this fix.I try to many time but can not solve.

Comment: What version are you using, we distrubute it as AAR files now. not JAR